# Auto-execute a function after everything else has executed

Tags: php

Basically, I have a script that is included at the top of a page that does a bunch of things, the most important being an ob_start(). Then in the body of the page I have a variety of tags that will be replaced, such as {hello_word}. Then at the very end, I include another script that ends the output buffer, and makes the tag replacements with other code, then prints.

Is there any possible way to do this without having to include my second file at the end? Is there some simple way I can automatically execute a function or include a file at the very end?

Comment: See [`auto_append_file`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file) and [`register_shutdown_function`](http://us.php.net/register_shutdown_function). The first one is only settable PERDIR, the second one is more flexible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register a function to be executed at the very end of script using [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [auto_append](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file) setting in php.ini, but you'll sacrifice portability. If you don't plan on distributing your application, this is a good option.

Comment: PREpend will execute BEFORE everything else. The OP wants the opposite.

Comment: I actually linked to the documentation for append, but typed in prepend by accident

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind, but I will be distributing this.

Answer (score 1):

Any objects that you have remaining will be destroyed at the end of the script, and their destructors will be called [(manual)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).  You can put code that you want executed at the end in the destructor.

For example:

```
Class Waitforme {

  function __destruct() {
    echo "I'm here!";
  }

}

$hello = new Waitforme();
```

This will do nothing until `$hello` is destroyed, at which time we'll see "I'm here!"

Comment: What if there are multiple classes with destructors?

Comment: All the destructors get called, and in an arbitrary order.